# Where to find out about QGIS new versions?

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w

What's the right way to find out about new current QGIS version releases?

I'm on Win64 and use OSGeo4W.
The [roadmap](https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html) gives dates for new releases, confirmed by the [main web site header](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) which lists time until next freeze.

However, while the time until next freeze shifted over on schedule on 22 March, the text still says current version is 3.6.0 (3.4.5 LTR). I tried over the weekend, and at the time the OSGeo4W installer still said latest was 3.6.0-1. I reran the installer this morning, and it had silently shifted over to 3.6.1, which I've now installed. I've since found that the release of 3.6.1 is also listed in the [GitHub commits list](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commits/release-3_6). However, the main website still lists 3.6.0.

All of this makes me think I'm painstakingly sleuthing in back alleyways while notification of release is probably blazing in neon lights if I merely looked in the right place. But what is that right place?

I'm perhaps overeager, but I wasted a day a month ago doing a careful workaround for something that had just been fixed in 3.6.0, I just didn't know it was out since the main website took a while past release date to update and I wasn't really paying attention. And I have a pesky intermittent crash I'm perhaps overoptimistically thinking will miraculously disappear in a new release.

Comment: I tend to have the `Check QGIS version at startup` option enabled in _Settings_ which does this automatically.

Comment: Coming back with an interim update: Watching releases on GitHub looks as if it will trigger on 3.x releases but not 3.x.x; will accept that answer if it works for 3.8. "Check QGIS version at startup" does not seem to work reliably for me, though doing a manual "Check QGIS version" from the Help menu works a few days after release. Maybe I just need to be less impatient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got you right.

Since you mentioned the Github repository, did you try to *Watch* > *Releases Only* on https://github.com/qgis/QGIS?

Check your settings at https://github.com/settings/notifications to direct notifications to email or web channel.

Comment: Thanks, klaus. I'm not actually currently a developer (of anything), so I'm not (currently) signed up as a member of GitHub. But yes, that's something I can do if indeed github is the right place to be looking rather than somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion (3 mos ago); unfortunately doesn't work the way it should. Didn't trigger on the April or May releases, nor on last week's genuine point release (3.8). Oh well, I just check manually.

Comment: This has now worked for the last 3 releases, so I assume the devs now trigger something in github which creates the notification. Therefore marking as accepted.